# What exactly does the forward function output in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

This example is taken verbatim from the [PyTorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html). Now I do have some background on Deep Learning in general and know that it should be obvious that the `forward` call represents a forward pass, passing through different layers and finally reaching the end, with 10 outputs in this case, then you take the output of the forward pass and compute the `loss` using the loss function one defined. Now, I forgot what exactly the output from the `forward()` pass yields me in this scenario.

I thought that the last layer in a Neural Network should be some sort of activation function like `sigmoid()` or `softmax()`, but I did not see these being defined anywhere, furthermore, when I was doing a project now, I found out that `softmax()` is called later on. So I just want to clarify what exactly is the `outputs = net(inputs)` giving me, from this [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/two-output-nodes-for-binary-classification/58703/2), it seems to me by default the output of a PyTorch model's forward pass is logits?

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()

import torch.optim as optim

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        print(outputs)
        break
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Comment: There is no such thing as _default_ output of a forward function in PyTorch.

Comment: When no layer with nonlinearity is added at the end of the network, then basically the output is a real valued scalar, vector or tensor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> it seems to me by default the output of a PyTorch model's forward pass
> is logits

As I can see from the forward pass, yes, your function is passing the raw output

```
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

So, where is softmax? Right here:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

It's a bit masked, but inside this function is handled the [softmax computation](http://%20https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) which, of course, works with the raw output of your last layer

This is softmax calculation:

[image: softmax]

where z_i are the raw outputs of the neural network

So, in conclusion, there is no activation function in your last input because it's handled by the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` class

Answering what's the raw output that comes from `nn.Linear`: The raw output of a neural network layer is **the linear combination** of the values that come from the neurons of the previous layer

Comment: Thank you! So to say, that if my previous of the linear layer (last layer) has 20 neurons/output values, and my linear layer has 5 outputs/classes, I can expect the output of the linear layer to be an array with 5 values, each of which is the linear combination of the 20 values multiplied by the 20 weights + bias?

Comment: @ilovewt yes, that's correct. Then the raw output is combined in the loss with softmax to output probabilities

Comment: What I did for me to find the `softmax` predictions is something like: `softmax_preds = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)(input=raw_outputs ).to('cpu').detach().numpy()`. Because even though `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` does incorporate `softmax` inside, all it does is give me the loss when I call `loss = criterion(raw_outputs, labels)`. Is this right?

Comment: @ilovewt yes it is correct. Anyway, I suggest you to open a new question if you have any new problem/implementation issues that you didn't understand from the doc ( pytorch is very well documented :) https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html,  https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/deep_learning_tutorial.html). This is because it's better to be on topic for your current question

Comment: Got it, may I know, if it's acceptable to @ you in future questions, I don't think there will be many, as I slowly started to pick up the pace.

Comment: feel free to tag me. Unfortunately I am not so expert of pytorch (I know better keras\tf :)). If I know the answer I'll help